# Logarithmic Time Scheme Algorithm

Tags: algorithm, scheme, time-complexity

I am currently working my way through the Scheme book "Concrete Abstractions" by Hailperin, Kaiser, and Knight. I've written recursive and iterative versions of the same algorithm shown below. The algorithm is used to perform an operation on a quantity or thing n number of time. So, generally, together-copies-of(operation n thing). For example, I could find 3 cubed like so, together-copies-of(* 3 3) or 3 squared together-copies-of(* 2 3).

Recursive version:

```
(define together-copies-of-linrec
  (lambda (combine quantity thing)
    (define together-iter
      (lambda (combine start thing)
        (if (= start quantity)
            thing
            (combine (together-iter combine (+ start 1) thing)
                     thing))))
      (together-iter combine 1 thing)))
```

Iterative version:

```
(define together-copies-of-linit
  (lambda (combine quantity thing)
    (define together-iter
      (lambda (combine start newthing)
        (if (= start quantity)
            newthing
            (together-iter combine (+ start 1) (combine newthing thing)))))
    (together-iter combine 1 thing)))
```

Now, I need to write a logarithmic-time version of this algorithm, but I don't really know where to start. I don't see how I can decrease the operations per instance to make it logarithmic-time in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that `combine` is guaranteed to be referentially transparent<sup>0</sup>, you can write a logarithmic-time version of this by looking at the whole computation as a binary tree<sup>1</sup>.  For instance, imagine the call `(together-copies-of * 4 3)` as a binary tree (abbreviating `together-copies-of` as `t`):

```
               (t * 4 3)
                   |
               ----*-----
              /          \
             /            \
       (t * 2 3)         (t * 2 3)
           |                 |
      -----*-             ---*----
     /       \           /        \
(t * 1 3) (t * 1 3) (t * 1 3) (t * 1 3)
```

The point here is that you don't need to calculate `(t * 1 3)` four times, and you don't need to calculate `(t * 2 3)` twice; you only need to calculate each of them once.  If we make sure that we only calculate the computations at each row once, then we'll only need to perform O(1) operations per row.  Since the number of rows in a binary tree is logarithmic in the number of elements, this means we have the workings of an O(log n) algorithm.

In contrast, your current algorithm looks like this:

```
(t * 4 3)
    |
  3 *
     \
  (t * 3 3)
       |
     3 *
        \
     (t * 2 3)
         |
       3 *
          \
       (t * 1 3)
          |
        3 * 3
```

That's what makes your program (both of them) linear: its structure is that of a big line, so it necessarily takes linear time.

The following simple program implements the binary tree idea.

```
(define together-copies-of-log
  (lambda (combine quantity thing)
    (if (= quantity 1)
        thing
        (let ((child (together-copies-of-log combine (/ quantity 2) thing)))
          (combine child child)))))
```

Since I just wrote that quickly to demonstrate the concept, it has a few deficiencies:

1. It fails if `quantity` isn't a power of two.
2. It isn't tail-recursive.

Fixing these is left as an exercise to the reader. `:)`

---

<sup>*A couple clarifying remarks:*</sup>

<sup>0:  Why does `combine` need to be referentially transparent?  If it weren't, then changing two calls to `combine` into one might actually alter the value, so it wouldn't be a valid transformation to make.</sup>

<sup>1:  Why a binary tree, as opposed to a ternary tree, or any other-ary tree?  It's because `combine` takes exactly two arguments.  If you were writing a version for different-arity functions, the tree would have the same arity.</sup>